# BLE Missing Packets (Protocol / Spec question)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, protocols, specifications, packet, loss

I have been learning the nuts and bolts of BLE lately, because I intend to do some development work using a BLE stack. I have learned a lot from the online documentation and the spec, but there is one aspect that I cannot seem to find.

BLE uses frequency hopping for communication. Once two devices are connected (one master and one slave), it looks like all communication is then initiated via the master and the slave responds to each packet. My question involves loss of packets in the air. There are two major cases I am concerned with:

1. Master sends a packet that is received by the slave and the slave sends a packet back to the master. The master doesn't receive the packet or if it does, it is corrupt.
2. Master sends a packet that is not received by the slave.

Case 1 to me is a "dont care" (I think). Basically the master doesn't get a reply but at the very least, the slave got the packet and can "sync" to it. The master does whatever and tries transmitting the packet at the next connection event.

Case 2 is the harder case. The slave doesn't receive the packet and therefore cannot "sync" its communication to the current frequency channel.

How exactly do devices synchronize the channel hopping sequence with each other when packets are lost in the air (specifically case 2)? Yes, there is a channel map, so the slave technically knows what frequency to jump to for the next connection event. However, the only way I can see all of this happening is via a "self timed" mechanism based on the connection parameters. Is this good enough? I mean, given the clock drift, there will be slight differences in the amount of time the master and slave are transmitting and receiving on the same channel... and eventually they will be off by 1 channel.. 2 channels, etc. Is this not really an issue, because for that to happen 'a lot' of time needs to pass based on the 500ppm clock spec? I understand there is a supervisor timer that would declare the connection dead after no valid data is transferred for some time. However, I still wonder about the "hopping drift", which brings me to the next point.

How much "self timing" is employed / mandated within the protocol? Do slave devices use a valid start of packet from the master every connection interval to re synchronize the channel hopping? For example if the (connection interval + some window) elapses, hop to the next channel, OR if packet received re sync / restart timeout timer. This would be a hop timer separate from the supervisor timer.

I can't really find this information within the core 5.2 spec. It's pretty dense at only over 3000+ pages... If somebody could point me to the relevant sections in the spec or somewhere else.. or even answer the questions, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slave knows the channel map. If one packet is not received from the master, it will listen again after one connection interval on the next channel. If that it also not received, it adds one extra connection interval and next channel.

The slave also stores a timestamp (or event counter) when the last received packet from the master was detected, regardless of if the crc was correct or not. This is called the anchor point. This is not the same time point used for supervision timeout.

The amount of time between the anchor point and the next expected packet is multiplied by the master + slave accuracy (for example 500 ppm) to get a receive window, plus 16 microseconds. So the slave listens this amount of time before and after the expected packet time of arrival.

Comment: Looks like the relevant information I wanted is within Vol 6 of the BLE phy in the 5.2 core spec - found after searching for "anchor". So the slave gets the channel map and self times within a receive window to receive a packet. If it gets nothing, there are a bunch of rules, but it moves to the next channel one interval later and listens in that window and continues like you said. There is a specific sentence that also states that the slave must update (sync) its timing each time it gets the first packet from the master @ an event (Vol 6, s4.5.7). This gives me enough to chew on. Accepted.